# Rails 3: Update database and scaffold

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

I'm starting in the big wooly world of Ruby on Rails and i'm trying to get my head around scaffolds and models. (cue, I'm a designer)

I use the rails generate scaffold command

```
rails generate scaffold Lesson title:string description:text
```

But is it possible to update the Lesson table with new key, values with rails?

I tried:

```
rails generate model Lesson title:string description:text dtstart:datetime
```

But when I run the db:migrate it fails and the only way around I know of to do that is to delete all of the scaffold and regenerate it.

I'm sure there must be an easier solution :)

I think (but im not sure, that it is because of the db/development.sqlite3 file that is not updated, when I delete the content by hand it then run the bd:migrate) is there a way to have evrything updated at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do what you describe - generally if you want to add new fields to a model, you want to generate a migration:

```
rails g migration AddStartToLesson
```

Then open the migration file and add the code that will add those fields. It will probably end up looking something like this:

```
class AddStartToLesson < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :lessons, :start, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :lessons, :start
  end
end
```

And you'll have to update some of the views - probably _form.html.erb, to get the form field to enter that data, and index.html.erb and show.html.erb to display it. (they're probably in app/views/lessons/)

Comment: 1.3 Changing Migrations
Occasionally you will make a mistake when writing a migration. If you have already run the migration then you cannot just edit the migration and run the migration again: Rails thinks it has already run the migration and so will do nothing when you run rake db:migrate. You must rollback the migration (for example with rake db:rollback), edit your migration and then run rake db:migrate to run the corrected version.

Comment: @YannickSchall Good point... while developing it's often easier to rollback and rewrite the migration that creates a model, rather than writing a new migration.

Comment: But is it possible to modify the structure of the database table during development, without having to regenerate the scaffold?

Comment: Arg, i'm an idiot, thought I made a comment on my own question ... This said, is it the same process to remove a field? write a new migration with only self.down?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html seems to have the answer. Now I have to try :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must also update (in rails 5 at least) your lesson_params in lessons_controller.rb in order to allow the new parameters to be passed from the view to the model.